# javascript open url with class in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Hi i want to open a url with all attributes that have the url for open popup

the attribute for open a popup come from class "colorbox-load"

> the code that i have is this

```
var urlcompleta = location.origin + 'buscador-agenda';
var url = '<a class="url-agenda colorbox-load" href="' + urlcompleta + '?width=500&height=500&iframe=true"></a>';
$('.calendar-agenda-items').click(function(event) {
    window.location = url;
});
```

this open the url of this mode
https://stackoverflow.com/

I need open with the attributes of url that detect the class and parameters

any idea? thanks
sorry for my english, if need correct please edit the post

Answer (score 1):

First off, `window.location` wants a URL, not an entire HTML tag. In simpler terms, it just wants the `href` property from your `<a>`.

If you're trying to open a new window with a width of 500 and a height of 500, you would do so using `window.open()` rather than `window.location`.  Seeing as you are hard-coding these values, I'm assuming that 500 is a static value.

In the event this is true, just do this:

```
var urlcompleta = location.origin + 'buscador-agenda';
var url = urlcompleta + '?width=500&height=500&iframe=true';
$('.calendar-agenda-items').click(function(event) {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=500,height=500");
});
```

**EDIT:** After reading this a few times and analyzing your comments, I'm starting to think that you want to simulate an `<a>` click when someone clicks that button. Maybe something like this?

```
var urlcompleta = location.origin + 'buscador-agenda';
var url = '<a id="myLink" style="display: none;" class="url-agenda colorbox-load" href="' + urlcompleta + '?width=500&height=500&iframe=true"></a>';
$('.calendar-agenda-items').append(url);
$('.calendar-agenda-items').click(function(event) {
    $('#myLink').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: no working because colorbox library need specify the class colorbox-load if this no exist in the url that i construct no open popup, the specification of you tell, open a new window, but need really with this library colorbox. How can open a url that i construct with javascript with all from a, thanks for you answer

Comment: @JonathanRodriguez Try my edit. I'm having difficulty understanding what you want but have tried an alternate solution.